# Returning just one integer from a list within a list using lambda C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int location { get; set; }
    public List<int> slots { get; set; }    
}
```

Then I have a list of customers:

```
List<Customer> lstCustomer = new List<Customer>();
```

Then I have a slot number:

```
int slot = 4;
```

I would like to return an integer of a specific location that the slot belongs to.  (See customer class above)

This is what I have so far:

```
int? location = lstCustomer
  .Where(l => l.slots.Any(x => slot))
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

But this does not work (`Error: Cannot convert int to bool`). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `Any(x => x == slot)`?

Comment: Also if you just want the `locaction` you'll need a `Select(x => x.location)` between the `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`.  That or a `?.location` after the `FirstOrDefault` to get `int?`

Comment: `l => l.slots.Contains(slot)`

Comment: Is `slots` guaranteed to have unique values across all customers? Or might you have more than one customer with the same slot? This whole thing seems very suspect

Comment: Musefan, slots is guaranteed to be unique in just one customer.

Comment: "List within a list" look like a duplicate of "SQL `in` in LinQ "

Comment: I don't understand your question. an example would help to better understand your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int? location = lstCustomer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.slots.Contains(slot))?.location;
```

Comment: that `if` not needed and can be reduced to `location = customer?.location`

Comment: Thanks Sander! I was just trying to avoid having to do it in two statements.  Is there any way to accomplish above in just one statement?

Comment: Your first line can just be: `var customer = lstCustomer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.slots.Contains(slot));`.  If you want it all as one line:  `int? location = lstCustomer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.slots.Contains(slot))?.location;`

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you.

Comment: team effort ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
var location = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slots.Any(s => s == 4))?.Location;
```

Here is an example console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var customers = new List<Customer>();

            customers.Add(new Customer { Location = 1, Slots = new List<int>() { 1, 2 } });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Location = 2, Slots = new List<int>() { 3, 4 } });

            var location = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slots.Any(s => s == 4))?.Location;

            Console.WriteLine(location); // returns 2
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Location { get; set; }
        public List<int> Slots { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was writing an answer in the same time as Sander so I didn't see that an answer already exists

Comment: Much appreciated, and you also showed me a different way to solve it using the "Any" keyword  I wrote it down in my notes.  Also thank you for the example.  Thank you again.